segmentation fault in c++ programme
output
the below code is a c++ program that calculates the sum of the letters in given text.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int letter_sum(string text)
{
    int Psum = 0;
    int n;
    while (text[n] != '\0')
    {
        n++;
        Psum = Psum + text [n];
    }
    int Rsum = Psum - (96*n);
    return Rsum;
}

int main ()
{
    string text;
    cout << "type the text: ";
    cin >> text;
    int displayvalue =letter_sum(text);
    cout << displayvalue << endl;
}

as per output I was expecting a num(which is sum of letters in given text ofcourse), but I got a error message showing segmentation fault.im a beginner to coding.so please explain in some easy terms and if possible tell me how to solve this problem.

This check text[n] != '\0' should be replaced with n < text.length().

What is the initial value of n?

And for your task, you could use a single std::accumulate call.

By the way, what is Psum - 96 * n supposed to do? What problem is that supposed to solve? What is the magic number 96 representing? That's a very good place to use comments to explain what you're doing and why.

@Someprogrammerdude I think it's to make the char 'a' count as 1, 'b' as 2, etc... :)

For some reason, I thought of: Why should I always enable compiler warnings?

#include <numeric> -- int letter_sum(string text) { return std::accumulate(text.begin(), text.end(), 0); }

There are two bugs in the code you provide:

The variable n is used (read)  uninitialised, which is undefined behavior.

When you iterate a std::string object the way you do, there is not a \0 terminator at the end. You need to either use begin() and end() iterators, check against the strings .size() or .length() or just use a range based for loop as in for (const auto& n : text) { ... } to avoid going out of bounds.



Isn't a null-terminator required since C++11?

@Someprogrammerdude Yes it is: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/strings#basic.string.general-3 - "In all cases, [data(), data() + size()] is a valid range, data() + size() points at an object with value charT() (a “null terminator”), and size() <= capacity() is true."

But there is also a third error: text[n] is checked to no be null, then n is increased, then text[n] is used. This is not a "program crashes" error, but it does mean that the first character of the string is missed (and a null value is added to the sum) - so in this case it won't be critical, but in general it is a Very Bad Idea to check text[n] and then use text[n+1]

@Frodyne "there is also a third error" -- However, as you noted, the third error is not an answer to why there is a segmentation fault.

@Someprogrammerdude "Isn't a null-terminator required since C++11?" - The question was just tagged "C++", not "C++11" or later, so I didn't want to assume anything (although I kind of did with the range based loop).

The value of n has to be initialized,
int n = 0;

If the value is not initialized, it will have a random garbage value like '16553072'. Thats why when accessing the index value of text[16553072], it goes beyond the memory assigned and it throws a segmentation fault.
Refer here to learn more about segmentation fault

there is no garbage. Its just not defined. The official term is indeterminate. The compiler knows when you access an array with indeterminate index and is free to emit code that does whatever. The compilers output does not necessariliy access any memory. The behavior of the code is undefined.
